# Connect to local ftp server via wireless connection

Tags: wireless-networking, ftp

I have created a local FTP server on Windows 7 and now I want to enable wireless feature on this FTP server. I want my clients to connect to my FTP via local wireless.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the FTP server is configured and ready to go. If that isn't the case, please update your question.

1. Figure it out the local IP address (Windows: ipconfig em Command Prompt, Linux: ifconfig in Terminal)
2. Install a FTP client ([FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/)?).
3. Use your IP address, then your FTP login and password.

This should work. Otherwise, leave a comment with the results..

Comment: I find that my local ip address is `192.168.1.145` now Why this ip changed every time?

Comment: Should i install FileZilla (server) too?

Comment: @ssss Your router is configured to change your IP address at every reboot. If your FTP server already works, there is no need to install FileZilla Server.

Comment: I set to `Anonymous` mode the FTP server, But now when i enter `127.0.0.3` on my browser, It require username and password!

Comment: wait, the IP of the server is 127.0.0.3 now?

Comment: No, the IPV4 address is `192.168.1.101`

Comment: then why are you connecting to 127.0.0.3 on your browser? what happens if you connect to 192.168.1.101?

Comment: I enter `192.168.1.101` and now opened a page that has a picture and write `IIS7` on it.(blue color)

Comment: try ftp:// 192.168.1.101 (with the ftp://)

Comment: it doesn't work with filezilla? try like this and show the error: https://mediacru.sh/ilnK4WiujkVG.png

Comment: I don't know my username and password, I made FTP as `Anonymous`

Comment: `Error: Could not connect to server`

Comment: then something is wrong with your FTP server. please update the question so others can be able to help you

Comment: Now it works, I create new FTP address with `127.0.0.1` and it works with browser and with FileZilla too.

Comment: Now, How clients can connect me with wireless connection? Should i create an access point on server?